# Firebase OrderBy treats a number field as a string

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to order a Firebase collection by a number field, but it keeps treating it as a string. It returns this order: 1, 10, 11, etc... instead of 1,2,3,4.

This is my query:

```js
const docSnap = await getDocs(collection(db, ...),
      orderBy("Order", "asc"));
```

The field "Order" is set as "number" in Firebase, and in console it does show as one - in green and without quote marks.

```js
0: Object { Tag: "grammar", Level: "beginner", Order: 1001, … }
```

Am I querying it in a wrong way? I would really appreciate your help.

EDIT: Here some additional information:

This is how my data looks like in Firebase:
[image]

This is how the console log of the query looks like (number 13 comes before number 9, for example). I tried adding "100X" to pad the number, but it didn't help:
[image]

Maybe the order is affected by the way I map the data afterwards? Here's the complete function:

```
  async function getChapters() {
const docSnap = await getDocs(collection(db, `${lang.native}${lang.target}chapters`),
  orderBy("Order", "asc"));
setChapters(docSnap.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data() })))
```

}

Comment: In my experience Firestore orders numbers correctly, not lexicographically. The code you shared also looks fine to me, so the problem is likely elsewhere. Can you share a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) somewhere where we can have a look at it, maybe on a site like StackBlitz or similar?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, I don't really know how to do this without publishing my firebase key... (I'll be grateful for a hint). Let me add some more info to the question and maybe you'll be able to spot the mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem, but it's working fine for me [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-ordering?file=index.js).

Code most relevant code from there:

```
let q = query(
  collection(db, "76772550"), 
  orderBy("Order")
 );

getDocs(q).then((querySnapshot) => {
  console.log(`Got ${querySnapshot.docs.length} results`);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data());
  })
})
```

The output I get from it:

> Got 3 results
> {Order: 9}
> {Order: 13}
> {Order: 42}

Which looks correct for the numerical data I put in.

If the problem persists for you, can you fork that StackBlitz and reproduce it - so that we're all looking at the same problem?

Comment: So I copied your exact way of querying data into my example and it worked! What seems to make the difference is using the following way: (const q = query(collection(...)) and then await getDocs(q)), rather than what I did before (await getDocs(collection(db...)). Now the order is correct. But I have no idea why that would make a difference?

Comment: I don't see the difference, but that might be because I still can't test with a minimal repro of the problem. If you fork my working StackBlitz example, can you change that to not work - and then share the link to that?